# Write file to UNC path in ASP

Tags: asp-classic

Somehow this code won't work:

```
Function WriteFile(FileName, XmlContent)
dim fs,fname
set fs= CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

set fname=fs.CreateTextFile("\\servername\folder\folder2\Xml.xml",true)
fname.write XmlContent
fname.Close
set fname=nothing
set fs=nothing

End Function
```

It shows an internal Error 500.

Everyone has access to this share and I can write/read fine from the path.

Is there anything i've missed?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What are the details of the error? 500 is a global HTTP error. But what does ASP say exactly?

Comment: I don't know. How do I catch that error? I am quite new to ASP.

Comment: After a little goolge if the error message to be Path Not Found

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was related to a network issue  because the UNC was on another network than the IIS server.

Thanks for you inputs anyway.